# How to log JSON or XML request in a database or log file before processing in Spring boot using @Requestbody annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How do I log a JSON or XML request in a database or log file before processing in Spring boot using `@RequestBody` annotation?

Using which class can I perform this?

Or any link would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter (`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` class) approach or you can use below code with custom implementation

```
@Component
public class AppRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, 
      Object handler) {
        HttpServletRequest requestCacheWrapperObject = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        //your implementation
        //sample method you can use: requestCacheWrapperObject.getParameterMap(); requestCacheWrapperObject.getContentAsByteArray();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(
      HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, 
      Object handler, 
      Exception ex) {
       //your implementation
    }
}


@Configuration
public class AppMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private AppRequestInterceptor appRequestInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(appRequestInterceptor)
          .addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to log request payloads, you can use Spring provided filter `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`.

Add following bean into your Spring-Boot config and change log level of `org.springframework.web.filter` package to **DEBUG**.

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter rlFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    rlFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    return rlFilter;
}
```

Also, Spring Boot provides Actuator Endpoint (/actuator/httptrace) for HTTP request logging out of the box. Check the below link for more details on this:

[Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)